# XCode 4.4 iOS 5.1 Simulator problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.4

i updated my mac book to mountain lion and Xcode to the 4.4 version.
In the pre version I had no problems with closing the iOS simulator and Xcode stopped automatically the building process but now if I close the iOS simulator the build process in Xcode is still running and I have to force quit Xcode because it freezes.

Does anyone recognize this bug, or can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't close the iOS simulator while XCode is building to it. I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Try using the stop button instead of quitting the simulator.

Comment: I have this bug as well.  Sometimes, once the simulator is killed, xcode thinks it's still running.  It's not showing up in the activity monitor, and the only way to return to a good state is to force quit.  I just upgraded from Snow Leopard and previously had the xcode 4 beta on my system, so maybe I started from a weird spot or there's some library issue.

Comment: Same issue there after an upgrade to ML. would be interesting to know if new ML users (fresh install) encounter this too. Because it would be worth a clean reinstall...!

Comment: it's the same with a fresh install of mountain lion

Comment: Same issue with upgrade from Lion :(

Comment: Has anyone found a bug report that was actually filed with Apple for this.  This seems like a real bug.

Comment: I have the same issue. I did try ⌘R which brings up the window saying to Stop or Cancel the running task. So I stopped it. (of course it doesnt really stop it). Then I did ⌘B and it built successfully. But building doesnt really help. I still cant run the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I've noticed that Running (⌘ + R) and then Bulding (⌘ + B) product succesfully starts new simulator instance, although the old instances are still frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I just reverted to doing something I used to do when this started happening to me back in XCode 3.1 or something.

Press the STOP button in XCODE before you close or background the app in iOS SIMULATOR.

Then close the iOS SIMULATOR.